# Bidirectional communication with Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, bidirectional

I'd like to send JSON data from the client to my Node.js server via jQuery and Ajax (websockets not possible) and get a JSON response back. I'd do that via POST, but since the Node.js server is running separately from the Apache server (which delivers my client-side website), jQuery is falling back to GET messages due to the same-origin-policy.

What's the best way to fix that?

Comment: enable CORS on your server, or put the javascript on the node server.

Comment: Have a look at MDN's page on the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), especially "*Changing origin*" and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). For the latter, also note [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors). Otherwise, either implement a proxy script in the Apache server to pass messages between the browser and Node.js or consolidate to a single server/origin.

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS, add `cors` in node.js file:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```